# shell script that takes a string input by the user and outputs the number of characters in it?

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi

Please can you show me a shell script that takes a string input by the user and outputs the number of characters in it? I have tried numerous times but i can't get it right.

Comment: add what you've tried to the question, and what the problem was.

Comment: Have you also tried using `wc -c`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the wc function like that:

```
echo -n abc | wc -c
```

or

```
echo -n abc | wc -m
```

The -n supresses the final newline which would count as an extra character.
check manual for [wc](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo -n "$1" | wc -c
```

wc is a tool to count characters, lines or bytes. -c is the option for characters.
The -n option for echo avoids the newline which would be an extra character.

Make sure to make the script executable by:

```
chmod +x wordcount.sh
```

So you will get:

```
user@host$ ./wordcount.sh "My String"
9
```